# Capture MouseHover event on ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, menu, notifyicon

I am using a `NotifyIcon` control, associated with a `ContextMenuStrip` to display a multi-level menu. I need to load the new branch of the submenu, when the user's mouse hovers on selected item.

Unfortunately, `ContextMenuStrip` does not have event for capturing `MouseHover` events, so I would like to use `ToolStripMenuItem` controls, instead of standard `ToolStripItem` controls.

`ToolStripMenuItem` has an event called `MouseHover`, but I need one event handler for all items in the menu. I don't have an idea how I can do that. Below is part of my code, which I use to add an event handler to a single `ToolStripMenuItem`.

```
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
mi.Text = "Hello";
Menu.Items.Add(mi);

mi.MouseHover += new EventHandler(mi_MouseHover);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a specific Event Handler to use it for all Tool Strip Menu Items

```
    private void ToolStripHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

```
 mi.MouseHover += new EventHandler(ToolStripHover);
```

Or you can copy `ToolStripHover` and paste it to each Menu Item's `MouseHover` event if you are using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.mouseenter.aspx) event for this..